# IPv6 Readiness for Java Developers

Tags: java, network-programming, ipv6

ARIN recommends `IPv6` readiness by January 2012 (3 days!!!).  I was wondering what implications (*if any*) does this mean for Java developers or Java EE server admins (GlassFish, Tomcat, etc.)?

I *believe* Java 1.4+ provides IPv6, but not sure if its something that all happens automagically underneath the "Java hood" or if there are real, manual changes that us Java folk will have to look out for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but now is the time to get a test environment with IPv6 up and running. You never know if you'll hit a subtle bug. And you'll want to have basic answers ready when your customers come to you asking about IPv6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Networking IPv6 User Guide for JDK/JRE 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/) for a good reference.

As long as you stick to pure Java functions, most (all?) Java applications are prepared for IPv6 without changing a single line of code, or even recompiling, since Java 1.4.

However, as praseodym below points out, there is one exception: if you are storing, using or manipulating raw IPv4 addresses (which are 32-bit) you will need to make changes to allow for 128-bit IPv6 addresses.

Comment: To elaborate: you're fine if you use only Java functions; your code will connect to IPv6 resources just fine. If you are, however, storing, using or manipulating raw IPv4 addresses you will need to make changes to allow for 128-bit IPv6 addresses.

Comment: relevant excerpt: "There should be no change in Java application code if everything has been done appropriately. I.e., **there are no direct references to IPv4 literal addresses; instead, hostnames are used.**"